# How do I make make multiple pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

1. I created a repository with the name username.github.io (Used my username). Does the case (a-A) matter? I made it with lowercase letters then renamed it to the exact casing.
2. If I have to make the repository with the name "username.github.io", how do I setup multiple pages?

I'm going to http://username.github.io and I don't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://pages.github.com/) (step #5), the first time you do this it'll take a couple of minutes to show up. Also, you have to be sure that the name of the repository *exactly* matches your username on GitHub, including case.

For multiple pages, just make multiple HTML files (or whatever) in the root of your repository.

Comment: Oh so you can make folders inside the repository to indicate different pages/projects? How do I view them in github.io? Is it username.github.io/folder/file.html ?

Comment: @ECMAScript Yes, you can

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? It's been 30 minutes since I uploaded and published my page. I'm still seeing page not found.

Answer (score 0):

1-Beacuase of dns propagation delay it takes a while for your site to show up.

2-To create a page just create an html file in root directory of your repo. also you can create it inside any other path then you can access it via :

```
username.github.io/anyotherpath/page.html
```

3-You can also use jekyll which is static site generator written in Ruby.

Comment: According to this https://pages.github.com/ do I have to make the repository my username.github.io, or can I just name the branch gh-pages?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can have only one subdomain of github.io per account